# Show that $\det D = a \det D_{n-1}- b^2 \det D_{n-1}$ for $n = 2, 3,\dots$

Tags: linear-algebra

My problem

> Consider the matrix
>   $$
>     D_n = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
>     a & b & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
>     b & a & b & \ddots & \vdots \\
>     0 & b & a & \ddots & 0 \\
>     \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & b\\
>     0 & \cdots & 0 & b & a \\
>     \end{bmatrix}}_{n \text{ columns}}
> $$ 
>   Show that $\det D_{n} = a \det D_{n-1} - b^2 \det D_{n-2}$ for $n = 2, 3,\dots$

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Are you sure that the formula is right? Should there be a $+$ or a $-$ in there?

Comment: I asked the question beacause i really have now idea how to solve this problem, I just need some help getting started with it.

Comment: It shuld be right now @TheoBendit

Comment: Have you tried expanding with cofactors?

Comment: Also, you're missing a $_n$ on the left side, and I suspect that there should be a $D_{n - 2}$ on the right?

Answer (score 1):

Write $D_n$ in two equivalent ways:
$$D_n =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & \begin{matrix}b & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix}b \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{matrix} & D_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & \begin{matrix}0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{matrix} \\
b & a & \begin{matrix}b & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{matrix} & \begin{matrix} b \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{matrix} & D_{n-2}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

If we expand the cofactors down the first column, from the first of the two matrices, our first term will be $aD_{n-1}$. For the second term, we appeal to the second representation; we get
$$-b \det
\begin{bmatrix}
b & \begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{matrix} \\
\begin{matrix}b \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{matrix} & D_{n-2}
\end{bmatrix},$$
which we can expand along the top row, to get
$$-b^2 \det D_{n-2}.$$
The rest of the column is $0$, so our total determinant is
$$\det D_n = a \det D_{n-1} - b^2 \det D_{n - 2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

The recursion should be $\text{det }D_n = a\text{det }D_{n-1}-b^2\text{det}D_{n-2}$. Try expanding the determinant of $D_n$ over the first row. The answer follows!

Comment: $$ det D_{n-2} : b * det  \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b & 0 & \cdots  \\
    b & a & b & \ddots \\
    0 & b & a & \ddots  \\
    0 & \cdots & 0 & b  \\
    \end{bmatrix}}_{n \text{ columns}}
$$

Comment: One more hint: $D_n = \begin{bmatrix}a & b & 0 \ldots & 0\\
b &\\
0 \\
\vdots& & D_{n-1}\\
0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Then:. 
$$
    b * b * det \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
    a & b & 0  \\
    b & a & b \\
    0 & b & a \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}}_{n \text{ columns}}
$$
= b^{2}det D_{n-2}