# Weird notation in a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I am trying to solve this problem, but I am unsure what the problem is even asking. Also I have never seen such a matrix before:

> Consider the matrix $$D_n=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&0&\dots&0\\b&a&b&\ddots&\vdots\\0&b&a&\ddots&0\\\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&a&b\\0&\dots&0&b&a\end{bmatrix}$$ Show that $$\det D_n=a\det D_{n-1}-b^2\det D_{n-2}$$ for $n=2,3,\dots$

Comment: Note the this precise question was posted just yesterday [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180784/show-that-det-d-a-det-d-n-1-b2-det-d-n-1-for-n-2-3-dots).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that the matrix carries on with the same pattern. So if $n=3$, $$
D_3=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&0\\b&a&b\\0&b&a\end{pmatrix}
$$
If $n=5$, 
$$
D_5=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&0&0&0\\b&a&b&0&0\\0&b&a&b&0\\0&0&b&a&b\\0&0&0&b&a\end{pmatrix}$$
etc.

Comment: Thanks! Shouldnt it be a b on row 3 column 4?

Comment: @JokkeMedKniven yep haha, good spot

Comment: Haha good! Do you have any clue on how to start with this problem by any chance?

Comment: @JokkeMedKniven I'll give a hint, consider expanding the determinant of the matrix $D_n$ about the first row. Do you need more than that?

Comment: No thats very helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2):

On the principal diagonal all the elements are equal to $a$, on the diagonals just above and below they are all equal to $b$, and zero everywhere else. I guess the $n$ stands for the dimension of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you! makes sense